# Installing Ubuntu 18.04 on SSD + two joined (2TB) HDDs

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, ssd

I am looking for a step by step tutorial on how to install Ubuntu 18.04. I will be using the desktop edition, as I like the interface (also using [putty](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/putty.1.html) for any add-on program for my server)

My main goal is to have the following, I will be doing a fresh new install of Ubuntu (have backup so I don't really care about deleting everything, still learning, from Microsoft to Linux is quite the change for me)

My First drive is an SSD (500G)
Second drive is a 2TB HD (Seagate)
Third drive is a 2TB HD (Seagate)

I would like to have Ubuntu installed on my SSD and the pair of 2TB HDDs open to add files; they need to coupled as I like to have everything in one place. I am building a home server, which again I am learning. Got the LAMP server and all which will be adding WordPress for personal use.

How it was set up, I had the main user aka initial log on user and created a new user for [vsftpd](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/vsftpd) so I can add files to this "New" user. I have over 2 TB of data and would like to have both the 2TB drives act as one, so I don't need to link folders. I like the way my folders are organized.

Question... How would I set up the initial installation of Ubuntu 18.04 to my SSD so as to have the 2TB act as one?

SSD should be /root?
Second drive (2 TB HDD #1) as swap?
Third drive (2 TB HDD #2)  as /home?

I am just confused, as in Windows you can install Windows on C: and have multiple drives coupled as one (the pair of 2 TB HDDs acting as one 4 TB drive), which I have on my Windows PC. I would like to do the same with this spare computer. How, if possible (I know it is) would I make this happen?

Thank you in advance, you are all awesome and been learning so much about this.

Dohm

Comment: Your question unfortunately is too broad.  It all comes down to how do you want to set it up?  Running the two 2TB drives as one 4TB is fine, but you do need to remember that if one of those drives dies all the data is lost across both drives.  You can do those as a RAID 1 where you will lose 2TB of space, but you will gain a mirror of the drive in case one goes bad.  I have been running my Ubuntu on a SSD fine for a while now without any problems.  It would be best for you to determine how you want to configure your own server.

Comment: I don't mind if the data is lost on the drives (if it dies) as I do keep a backup of everything on a another computer so the info is secure on multiple HD's.

I would like to have the SSD (500gb) to have Ubuntu boot load and have all ubuntu normal install files on the ssd... and to have my second user, lets call this user Bob to have access to all that extra 4Tb space.

Comment: It's the initial step when you first install (doing a clean install) of ubuntu and what to select in order to achieve this.

Comment: You might want to ask this maybe at https://ubuntuforums.org/ where you can get into discussions about setting up your server and get lots of advice for it.  Here is actually a Q&A site for more direct questions.

Comment: Ok thank you, slow learner here lol.

Comment: LVM provides a method of allocating space on mass-storage devices that is more flexible than conventional partitioning schemes. In particular, a volume manager can concatenate, stripe together or otherwise combine partitions into larger virtual ones that administrators can resize or move, potentially without interrupting system use. Would it be OK to use LVM to span the /home partition across multiple drives by creating a logical volume for /home? /home would be located on a single logical volume that spans part of the SSD and all of the HDD.

Answer (score 1):

To close this question, I have found this:

```
mkdir /var/www/folder/stuff
mount --bind /home/user/ftp/files/ /var/location/stuff
```

I takes my other Drive location, which is an additional 2T and reference it as it was the same folder.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

To make things simple, let's keep the RAID separate from the system drive:

Install Ubuntu to SSD as / and follow Ubuntu's own steps here: http://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0 . A lot of things besides contents go into /home, so keeping it on the SSD is excellent; you will appreciate the speed it gives you.

Unless you intend to use [Hibernation](https://www.fosslinux.com/184/what-is-difference-between-suspend-and-hibernate-in-linux.htm) (unlikely on a web server), a swap partition is passe; Ubuntu will create a properly sized swap file automagically as a part of the install process.

Once installed and booted, you can then come back and add the HDDs from within your working installed Ubuntu, using [LVM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm), [RAID-0](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/advanced-installation.html), or [RAID-0 in LVM](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man7/lvmraid.7.html), whichever you prefer, to give you 4 TB of space, then [add that volume to /etc/fstab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive) so the combined HDDs automatically mount at boot and are easily accessible to store content.

Now that assumes you choose [ext4](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) for the Big Volume; ext4 is the Ubuntu default. However, you could use an alternative filesystem, such as [btrfs](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page). That would give you the ability to add more drives, of the same or different sizes, later to the volume, while providing more reliability than RAID-0 or LVM. That's because you can create a [btrfs multi-disk volume with mirrored metadata](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Using_Btrfs_with_Multiple_Devices), making recovery from a small error easier.

After that's done, then you can add User 'Bob', but let's keep things simple here, and keep the scope of this discussion limited so as not to make this any more complex than it needs to be.

You will have more questions; that's what we're here for.